# Java - RTSP save snapshot from Stream Packets

Tags: java, opencv, ffmpeg, rtsp

I'm developing an application which requests snapshots to DVR and IP Cameras. The device I'm working on just offer RTSP requests to do so. Then I implemented the necessary RTSP methods to start receiving the stream packets and I started receiving then via UDP connection established. My doubt is, how can I save the received data to a jpeg file? Where's the begging and end of the image bytes received?

I searched a lot libraries which implement this type of service in Java, like Xuggler ( which it's maintained no more ), javacpp-presets - has ffmpeg and opencv libraries included - I had some environment problems with it. If someone know an easy and good one which saves snapshots from the streams, let me know.

My code:

```
final long timeout = System.currentTimeMillis() + 3000;

byte[] fullImage = new byte[ 1024 * 1024 ];
DatagramSocket udpSocket = new DatagramSocket( 8000 );
int lastByte = 0;

// Skip first 2 packets because I think they are HEADERS
// Since I don't know what they mean, I just print then in hexa
for( int i = 0; i < 2; i++ ){

    byte[] buffer = new byte[ 1024 ];
    DatagramPacket dataPacket = new DatagramPacket( buffer, buffer.length );
    udpSocket.receive( dataPacket );

    int dataLenght = dataPacket.getLength();
    buffer = Arrays.copyOf( buffer, dataLenght );

    System.out.println( "RECEIVED[" + DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary( buffer ) + " L: " + dataLenght );

}

do{

    byte[] buffer = new byte[ 1024 ];
    DatagramPacket dataPacket = new DatagramPacket( fullImage, fullImage.length );
    udpSocket.receive( dataPacket );

    System.out.println( "RECEIVED: " + new String( fullImage ) );

    for( int i = 0; i < buffer.length; i++ ){
        fullImage[ i + lastByte ] = buffer[ i ];
        lastByte ++;

    }

} while( System.currentTimeMillis() < timeout );
// I know this timeout is wrong, I should stop after getting full image bytes
```

The output:

RECEIVED: 80E0000100004650000000006742E01FDA014016C4 L: 21
RECEIVED: 80E00002000046500000000068CE30A480 L: 17
RECEIVED: Tons of data from the streaming...
RECEIVED: Tons of data from the streaming...
RECEIVED: Tons of data from the streaming...
[...]

As you might suppose, the image I'm saving into a file is not readable because I'm doing it wrong. *I think* the header provide me some info about the next packets the server will sent me telling the start and the end of the image from the streaming. But I don't understood them. Someone know how to solve it? Any tips are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

First you have not specified what is the RTP payload type - is it jpeg, H.264 or some other media format? Given the payload you must look up the according rfc ([this](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2435) one is for JPEG, [this](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6184) one for H.264) and demux the RTP packet stream.